# Deleted folders still displaying when synchronize with repository

Tags: eclipse, svn

In my Java EE project, I changed the package name and commit with subversion in eclipse. The updated directories are committed successfully but shown error for old directories that they can't be deleted [Commit Failed. Out of date]. So that old and updated files are both in repository. Then I deleted old directories manually using `TortoiseSVN repo browser`. Now every time I synchronize with repository, the directory are still shown as they were not yet synchronized no matter how many time I try to commit. I've also tried `right click project folder -> Team -> Refresh/Cleanup`. But it doesn't work. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that the "Out of date" error you get should be related to the working copy and the repo not being in sync. Assuming you are on Linux, I would `cd` to the project directory, run `svn update` to update your project to what's in the repo, then `svn status` (what does it say about the files in question?), afterwards `svn delete [old files]` and finally `svn commit`.

Comment: I'm on windows. I run `svn update` from cmd and choose `(mc) keep affected local moves` then problem solved. Thanks :)